# jQuery loop over inputs and options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to loop over form fields and get the value.
What i'm expecting is `"key=primary_account_id&value=123&key=primary_account_first_name&value=rose&key=primary_account_last_name&value=kent"` and what I am getting from below code is `"key=primary_account_id&value=123"` thrice. Please let me know what am I missing. Thanks.

```
 <div class="search-field-form">
    <div class="custom-dd">
      <select class="searchField" name="search-field">
        <option value="primary_account_id" data-type="text">ID</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="answer search-text hide">
      <input type="text" name="search-value" value="123">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-field-form">
    <div class="custom-dd">
      <select class="searchField" name="search-field">
        <option value="primary_account_first_name" data-type="text">Primary First Name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="answer search-text hide">
      <input type="text" name="search-value" value="rose">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="search-field-form">
    <div class="custom-dd">
      <select class="searchField" name="search-field">
        <option value="primary_account_last_name" data-type="text">Last Name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="answer search-text hide">
      <input type="text" name="search-value" value="kent">
    </div>
  </div>
<script>
$('.search-field-form').each(function(){
console.log("key=" + $('.searchField').val() + "&value=" + $('.searchField').closest('.search-field-form').find('.search-text').find('input[name="search-value"]').val());
</script>
```

Comment: Use a form and `serialize`. Or with `serializeArray`. So much cleaner, so much easier: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: `$('.searchField')` will give you first element with that class name. You will need to find 'searchField' for each 'search-field-form'; in that case, `$(this).find('.searchField')` will give you what you want.

Comment: @LwinHtooKo thanks. Is this the efficient way to get the desired result?

Comment: @Swapnil check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$('.searchField')` to `$(this).find('.searchField')`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form, do below -

**HTML**

```
<form id="search-form">
    <div class="search-field-form">
        <div class="custom-dd">
            <select class="searchField" name="search-field">
                <option value="primary_account_id" data-type="text">ID</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="answer search-text hide">
            <input type="text" name="search-value" value="123">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-field-form">
        <div class="custom-dd">
            <select class="searchField" name="search-field">
                <option value="primary_account_first_name" data-type="text">Primary First Name</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="answer search-text hide">
            <input type="text" name="search-value" value="rose">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-field-form">
        <div class="custom-dd">
            <select class="searchField" name="search-field">
                <option value="primary_account_last_name" data-type="text">Last Name</option>
            </select>
        </div>
            <div class="answer search-text hide">
                <input type="text" name="search-value" value="kent">
            </div>
        </div>
    <button type="button" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#submit-btn').click(function() { 
        data = $('#search-form').serialize();
        data = data.replace(/search-field/g, 'key');
        data = data.replace(/search-value/g, 'value');
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

If you don't have a form, follow Hairmot's answer.